# Array iteration

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a question regarding the iteration of a 2d array. Why does this work with **System.out.println(n)** and not **System.out.println(row[n])**? I am trying to print all the numbers.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int numbers[][] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
        for (int [] row : numbers){

            for (int n: row){

                System.out.println(n);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? In your first foreach loop, what is row? An index, or an element of the array? So why would it be different for n?

Comment: Because `n` isn't an *index* in the row - it's an *element* in the row.

Comment: because `n` will at some point have the value 6, `row[6]` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

because you are eventually accessing numbers outside of the array. In this example, the first iteration it is `{1,2,3}`, and the second iteration it is `{4,5,6}`. The first 2 iterations over the first iteration (let's call it `x`), will work, because x[1] and x[2] are still in the array. After that, you are trying to print x[3], which is not in the array.

Same thing for the iterations over the second iteration (let's call it `y`).
You are trying to print y[4], y[5], y[6], but y only has 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

The first value of `n` is 1 and `row[1]` exists, it is the second item in `rows` (note that indexing starts from 0) but then `n` will be 2 and your array does not have a second element, just a 0th and a first, so you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.